# "Corrupted double-linked list" when using malloc() on a 2D array in a structure

Tags: malloc

I'm trying to make a small autoCompletion program.
I'm taking strings from a file and put them line by line in a 2D char type array.

This is my code :

Dictionnary.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "Dictionnary.h"

int getDictionnarySize(FILE *theDictionnary)
{  
  size_t pos = ftell(theDictionnary);
  fseek(theDictionnary, 0, SEEK_END);
  size_t len = ftell(theDictionnary);
  fseek(theDictionnary, pos, SEEK_SET);

  return (len);
}

int getNbLines(char *buff)
{
  int   lines = 1;
  int   i = 0;

  while (buff[i] != '\0')
    {
      if (buff[i] == '\n')
    lines++;
      i++;
    }

  return (lines);
}

int allocDictionnary(t_dictionnary *d, char *buff)
{
  d->lines = getNbLines(buff) - 1;
  int i;
  char str[2048];
  int len;

  rewind(d->dico);
  d->dictionnary = malloc(sizeof(*d->dictionnary) * d->lines);
  for (i = 0; i <= d->lines; i++)
    {
      memset(str, 0, 2048);
      fgets(str, 256, d->dico);
      len = strlen(str);
      printf("len = %d\n", len);
      d->dictionnary[i] = malloc(sizeof(**d->dictionnary) * len);
      if (d->dictionnary[i] == NULL)
    return (1);
      strcpy(d->dictionnary[i], str);
      printf("String is : %s\n", d->dictionnary[i]);
    }

  return (0);
}

int initDictionnary(t_dictionnary *d)
{
  int   size;
  char  *buff;

  if ((d->dico = fopen(d->theDictionnary, "r")) != NULL)
    {
      size = getDictionnarySize(d->dico);
      buff = malloc(size + 1);
      fread(buff, size, 1, d->dico);
      allocDictionnary(d, buff);
      fclose(d->dico);
    }
  else
    {
      return (1);
    }

  free(buff);
  return (0);
}

int killDictionnary(char **theDictionnary, int size)
{
  int   i = 0;

  while (i <= size)
    {
      free(theDictionnary[i]);
      i++;
    }
  free(theDictionnary);

  return (0);
}
```

Dictionnary.h

```
#ifndef __DICTIONNARRY_H__
# define __DICTIONNARY_H___

/* STRUCTURES */

typedef struct s_dictionnary
{
  const char *theDictionnary;
  FILE *dico;
  char **dictionnary;
  int lines;
}       t_dictionnary;

/* PROTOTYPES */

int     getDictionnarySize(FILE *theDictionnary);
int     allocDictionnary(t_dictionnary *d, char *buff);
int     initDictionnary(t_dictionnary *dico);
int     getNbLines(char *buff);
int     killDictionnary(char **theDictionnary, int size);

#endif /* __DICTIONNARY_H__ */
```

main.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Dictionnary.h"

int main(int ac, char **av)
{
  t_dictionnary d;

  d.theDictionnary = "./miniDico";
  initDictionnary(&d);
  killDictionnary(d.dictionnary, d.lines);
  return (0);
}
```

When I compile, i don't have any errors or warnings.
But when I run this I get :

```
*** Error in `./a.out': corrupted double-linked list: 0x0000000000f19550 ***
```

Valgrind result :

```
==4004== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==4004== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==4004== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==4004== Command: ./a.out
==4004== 
==4004== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==4004==    at 0x40095C: getNbLines (Dictionnary.c:22)
==4004==    by 0x40098B: allocDictionnary (Dictionnary.c:34)
==4004==    by 0x400B9F: initDictionnary (Dictionnary.c:67)
==4004==    by 0x400C42: main (main.c:10)
==4004== 
len = 35
==4004== Invalid write of size 1
==4004==    at 0x4C2D623: strcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4004==    by 0x400AB8: allocDictionnary (Dictionnary.c:50)
==4004==    by 0x400B9F: initDictionnary (Dictionnary.c:67)
==4004==    by 0x400C42: main (main.c:10)
==4004==  Address 0x51d8723 is 0 bytes after a block of size 35 alloc'd
==4004==    at 0x4C29F90: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4004==    by 0x400A61: allocDictionnary (Dictionnary.c:47)
==4004==    by 0x400B9F: initDictionnary (Dictionnary.c:67)
==4004==    by 0x400C42: main (main.c:10)
==4004== 
==4004== Invalid read of size 1
==4004==    at 0x4E7E1C2: vfprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==4004==    by 0x4E84E38: printf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==4004==    by 0x400AE5: allocDictionnary (Dictionnary.c:51)
==4004==    by 0x400B9F: initDictionnary (Dictionnary.c:67)
==4004==    by 0x400C42: main (main.c:10)
==4004==  Address 0x51d8723 is 0 bytes after a block of size 35 alloc'd
==4004==    at 0x4C29F90: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4004==    by 0x400A61: allocDictionnary (Dictionnary.c:47)
==4004==    by 0x400B9F: initDictionnary (Dictionnary.c:67)
==4004==    by 0x400C42: main (main.c:10)
==4004== 
String is : Paris, 458 boulevard Saint-Germain

len = 35
String is : Paris, 343 boulevard Saint-Germain

len = 44
String is : Marseille, 343 boulevard Camille Flammarion

len = 37
String is : Marseille, 29 rue Camille Desmoulins

len = 34
String is : Marseille, 1 chemin des Aubagnens

len = 25
String is : Paris, 12 rue des singes

len = 24
String is : Paris, 34 quai VoLtAiRe

len = 23
String is : Paris, 34 rue Voltaire

len = 33
String is : Lille, 120 boulevard Victor Hugo

len = 27
String is : Marseille, 50 rue Voltaire

len = 26
String is : Toulouse, 90 rue Voltaire

len = 30
String is : Strasbourg 84 rue du Bouclier

len = 42
String is : Marseille, 78 boulevard de la libération

len = 27
String is : Lille, 30 rue Victor Danel

len = 38
String is : Mont Saint Martin, 42 rue de Bordeaux

len = 47
String is : Mont de Marsan, 100 avenue Pierre de Coubertin

len = 35
String is : Strasbourg, 391 boulevard de Nancy

len = 38
String is : Lyon, 56 rue du Docteur Albéric Pont

len = 35
String is : Lyon, rue du Docteur Albéric Pont

len = 38
String is : 56 rue du Docteur Albéric Pont, Lyon

len = 19
String is : Lyon 56 grande rue

len = 24
String is : Lille, 90 rue d’Arras

len = 35
String is : Lille, 76 impasse Georges Pompidou

len = 25
==4004== Invalid write of size 8
==4004==    at 0x400A62: allocDictionnary (Dictionnary.c:47)
==4004==    by 0x400B9F: initDictionnary (Dictionnary.c:67)
==4004==    by 0x400C42: main (main.c:10)
==4004==  Address 0x51d86b8 is 0 bytes after a block of size 184 alloc'd
==4004==    at 0x4C29F90: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4004==    by 0x4009C3: allocDictionnary (Dictionnary.c:40)
==4004==    by 0x400B9F: initDictionnary (Dictionnary.c:67)
==4004==    by 0x400C42: main (main.c:10)
==4004== 
==4004== Invalid read of size 8
==4004==    at 0x400A7D: allocDictionnary (Dictionnary.c:48)
==4004==    by 0x400B9F: initDictionnary (Dictionnary.c:67)
==4004==    by 0x400C42: main (main.c:10)
==4004==  Address 0x51d86b8 is 0 bytes after a block of size 184 alloc'd
==4004==    at 0x4C29F90: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4004==    by 0x4009C3: allocDictionnary (Dictionnary.c:40)
==4004==    by 0x400B9F: initDictionnary (Dictionnary.c:67)
==4004==    by 0x400C42: main (main.c:10)
==4004== 
==4004== Invalid read of size 8
==4004==    at 0x400AA4: allocDictionnary (Dictionnary.c:50)
==4004==    by 0x400B9F: initDictionnary (Dictionnary.c:67)
==4004==    by 0x400C42: main (main.c:10)
==4004==  Address 0x51d86b8 is 0 bytes after a block of size 184 alloc'd
==4004==    at 0x4C29F90: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4004==    by 0x4009C3: allocDictionnary (Dictionnary.c:40)
==4004==    by 0x400B9F: initDictionnary (Dictionnary.c:67)
==4004==    by 0x400C42: main (main.c:10)
==4004== 
==4004== Invalid read of size 8
==4004==    at 0x400AD1: allocDictionnary (Dictionnary.c:51)
==4004==    by 0x400B9F: initDictionnary (Dictionnary.c:67)
==4004==    by 0x400C42: main (main.c:10)
==4004==  Address 0x51d86b8 is 0 bytes after a block of size 184 alloc'd
==4004==    at 0x4C29F90: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4004==    by 0x4009C3: allocDictionnary (Dictionnary.c:40)
==4004==    by 0x400B9F: initDictionnary (Dictionnary.c:67)
==4004==    by 0x400C42: main (main.c:10)
==4004== 
String is : Lyon, 2 allée des fleurs
==4004== Invalid read of size 8
==4004==    at 0x400BF6: killDictionnary (Dictionnary.c:85)
==4004==    by 0x400C53: main (main.c:11)
==4004==  Address 0x51d86b8 is 0 bytes after a block of size 184 alloc'd
==4004==    at 0x4C29F90: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4004==    by 0x4009C3: allocDictionnary (Dictionnary.c:40)
==4004==    by 0x400B9F: initDictionnary (Dictionnary.c:67)
==4004==    by 0x400C42: main (main.c:10)
==4004== 
==4004== 
==4004== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4004==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4004==   total heap usage: 27 allocs, 27 frees, 2,289 bytes allocated
==4004== 
==4004== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==4004== 
==4004== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==4004== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==4004== ERROR SUMMARY: 54 errors from 8 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: Not that it's immediately related to your problem, but `dictionary` only has one `n`.

Comment: What do you mean by one 'n' ?

Comment: I mean you appear to be spelling it `dictionnary` with _two_ `n`'s. The English word `dictionary` only has one, even for weird variants like American, with their quaint `-ize` spelling of otherwise sensible words :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this loop causing troubles:

```
for (i = 0; i <= d->lines; i++)
```

It seems that it should be (I've changed stop condition):

```
for (i = 0; i < d->lines; i++)
```

otherwise you write behind allocated space...

**UPDATE**

Clarification:

Allocating array with `d->dictionnary = malloc(sizeof(*d->dictionnary) * d->lines);` gives you an arry with exactly `d->lines` elements. It starts from `0` index and last element could be accessed with `d->lines-1` index. So when you use loop from `0` up to and including `d->lines` the very last loop cycle will write outside of array boundaries (i.e. to `d->lines` index). That's where you corrup your heap. Very often C runtime doesn't check for such errors and you will only see them on rare ocasions and probably far away from the code which caused them.

"corrupted linked list" is about heap corruption. Blocks allocated with `malloc` are usually chained into linked lists (this really depends on implementation of you memory allocator). So, when writing outside allocation boundaries - you can corrupt this list. Hence the complaint.

Comment: lines variable has been decremented by 1 at the top of the file.

Comment: d->lines = getNbLines(buff) - 1; so i have the exact nb of lines

Comment: but i don't have any errors... so that's the problem

Comment: @SebastienMercier please take a look at "update" section.